# constexpr with operator|=

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I tried to write a function, which returns an integer with only the highest bit of the input set, using a C++0x constexpr.

```
constexpr inline uint64_t
get_highest_bit(uint64_t p)
{
  return 
     (p|=(p>>1)),
     (p|=(p>>2)),
     (p|=(p>>4)),
     (p|=(p>>8)),
     (p|=(p>>16)),
     (p|=(p>>32)),
     (p-(p>>1));
}
```

This gives a compile-time failure using gcc 4.6.1.

```
error: expression ‘(p <unknown operator> ((p >> 1) | p))’ is not a constant-expression
```

Note that it works without the constexpr keyword.

My questions are:

Why does this not work?
I can see that operator|= is not a constexpr, but does it matter for built-in types?

Is there an easy way to write this function as a constexpr? I would like it to be reasonable efficient at runtime, and I care a bit about readibility.

Comment: You cannot perform assignment in a constant expression and you cannot use the comma operator (I'm not 100% sure about the comma operator; you certainly couldn't use it in C++03).  All you have to do is rewrite this so it doesn't use those two operators.  It should be straightforward using recursion.

Comment: Thanks fot the quick answer. the comma operator seems to be accepted by g++ 4.6.1 at least. I was not aware of forbidden assignment, and at first sight, it seems to make constexpr a lot less neat.

Comment: @DirkM: `constexpr` seems really neat, until you learn about all the restrictions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Not tested on GCC because I don't have 4.6, but I've verified that the algorithm is correct.)

To use `constexpr` you must not have assignments. Therefore, you often have to write in *functional* form with recursion:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>

constexpr inline uint64_t highestBit(uint64_t p, int n = 1) {
    return n < sizeof(p)*CHAR_BIT ? highestBit(p | p >> n, n * 2) : p - (p >> 1);
}

int main() {
    static_assert(highestBit(7) == 4);
    static_assert(highestBit(5) == 4);
    static_assert(highestBit(0x381283) == 0x200000);
    return 0;
}
```

You can check C++0x §[expr.const]/2 to see what expressions cannot be used in a `constexpr` function. In particular, the second to last item is "an assignment or a compound assignment".

Comment: That was insightful. I was hoping to get away from recursive tmeplate instantiations. It seems that I will have to learn to live with recursive constexpressions.

Comment: @DrikM: There are no templates involved, it's just plain recursion.

Comment: @Vitus: the original code (not published here) used templates to do the same as the constexpr here. (My comment was not very clear without context).

Answer (score 3):

```
constexpr inline uint64_t highestBit(uint64_t p)
{
    return (p & (p-1))? highestBit(p & (p-1)): p;
}
```

Each level of recursion clears the rightmost bit that was set, when the final bit would be cleared, only the highest bit remained, so it's returned.

Comment: Thanks, I picked the other answer because the worst-case recursion is less deep there, and the compiler could theoretically unroll it. (although, I will have to look closer at my usecase).

Comment: @DirkM: The compiler should unroll either one at compile time.  But when the argument isn't a constant, yes this one could involve more recursion (although, the compiler may still transform it to iteration with no additional function calls).